# Set default value to a checkbox in EXT JS (Sencha)

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox whose value is bound to a field from database. I want to set a default value 'true'/'checked' if the database contains null value.

The checkbox is :

```
xtype: 'checkbox',
bind: { value: '{database_variable_name}'},
fieldLabel: 'label_name'
```

I have tried this `formula` with no effect (checkbox remains unchecked):

```
bind: { value: '{checkboxFormula}'}
```

and

```
checkboxFormula: {
            get: function (get) {
                var value = get('database_variable_name');
                return (value == null) ? true : value;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.set('database_variable_name', value);
            }
}
```

The whole function works correctly if database does not return null, the checkbox is checked/unchecked accordingly. Any pointers to where I might be going wrong would be highly appreciated!

PS : Binding database variables is already in working condition.

Comment: Don't you think it's a better idea to handle this at the model level? I mean for the checkbox data field you could use a [convert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-convert) function.

Comment: Please check in the model whether `allowNull` is `false` on the field - in that case, you won't ever get a `null` from the model, only `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Alexander, the problem is that he wants null values to be set to true, as I see from his formula definition

Comment: @scebotari which doesn't work if the model already maps `null` values to `false` because `allowNull` is `false` on the field.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try out the  allowNull and convert function